# Make a left panel not auto collapsible in MS Teams

Tags: microsoft-office, microsoft-teams

After I pressed some keys on keyboard this panel has disappeared and now appears only on mouse hovering:

[image]

How do I lock it back again?

UPD. Below are some screenshots.

[image]

[image]

Comment: @harrymc I cannot find any "Preferences" item. Where it is?

Comment: When you go to Chat its normal for the Teams to go away & a Chat left bar to show up. You simply click Teams to get back to it. Could you screenshot what it looks like when that Teams left bar is missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to replicate your issue. When I changed the zoom level to 145% like you did & moved Teams to another monitor with smaller resolution (1024x768px) it hide this left bar. Teams is trying to give you more area for things with the limited room it has. This is normal & I don't think there is anyway to fix. Ideas:

1. Increase the resolution of your monitor
2. Turn down the zoom level in Teams
3. Adjust (DPI?) text size within Settings, System, Display, tweak top bar:
   [image]

Comment: You are right. Restoring the Zoom helped me. I think I changed the Zoom settings with some accidental key combination. Thanks a lot!

Comment: It's a good thing you snapped a picture of it since that's what queued me in ;)

Answer (score -2):

I was able to replicate your issue. When I changed the zoom level to 145% like you did & moved Teams to another monitor with smaller resolution (1024x768px) it hide this left bar. Teams it trying to give you more area for things with the limited room it has. This is normal & I don't think there is anyway to fix. Ideas:

Increase the resolution of your monitor
Turn down the zoom level in Teams

THIS!!!!!!  I looked everywhere to try and fix this. It's just the zoom. I'm dumb sometimes :)